# HtmlUnitDriver não econtra id do campo - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Estou usando Selenium para fazer uma automatização da ação do usuário do navegador. Estou utilizando o `HtmlUnitDriver`, para não abrir o navegador e não ter que apontar um `.exe`.

A página que estou realizando, vai mostrando os componentes de acordo com valores selecionados em combos. Quando altero a segunda combo é que começam os problemas, pois não acha o `id` do próximo.

Percebi que o código HTML nesse momento está diferente e por isso não encontra, só não estou conseguindo achar uma solução pra isso. Já utilizei o `wait` com condições, `thread.sleep`, encontrar o elemento por XPath, nada disso resolveu pra mim.

Código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);

    try{        

        driver.get("https://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/guiasinternet/Gare/Paginas/Gare.aspx");

        driver.findElement(By.id("ReceitaTipo")).click();

         {
           WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("ReceitaTipo"));
           dropdown.findElement(By.xpath("//option[. = 'GNRE']")).click();
         }

         //printar código fonte da pagina            
         System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());

         Thread.sleep(5000);

         driver.findElement(By.id("CodigoReceita")).click();

         {
           WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("CodigoReceita"));
           dropdown.findElement(By.xpath("//option[. = '10002.1 - Energia Elétrica']")).click();
         } 

         //A partir daqui para de funcionar
         System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());         

         driver.findElement(By.id("CnpjCpf")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.id("CnpjCpf")).sendKeys("087.271.516-54");   

         driver.quit();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que isso não sera possível de conseguir com HtmlUnitDriver no momento, mesmo em suas ultimas versões e mesmo com o

```
new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
```

O HtmlUnitDriver não tem um suporte tão interessante a execução de js, buscando pelo stackoverflow você vê que todo mundo que tenta algo do tipo, esta enfrentando problemas.

Na pagina em especifico que você esta tentando acredito que, quando você seleciona um código de receita ele executa algum script, porem através do HtmlUnitDriver não esta funcionando essa execução do script e a pagina não muda de estado.

Minha sugestão e solução temporária até o HtmlUnitDriver ter um melhor suporte é utilizar o chrome como headless, nesse caso você dependeria do executável mas não precisaria abrir o navegador, segue um exemplo onde você **tem o chromedriver.exe na pasta do seu projeto**:

```java
private WebDriver getHeadlessChrome() {
    try {
        //Sugiro manter o service fora desse método, isso aqui é apenas um exemplo.
        ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                .usingAnyFreePort()
                .usingDriverExecutable(new File("chromedriver.exe"))
                .build();
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions().addArguments("--headless");

        return new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Do something
    }
    return null;
}
```

Outra dica, quando estiver trabalhando com dropdown, sugiro que use 'Select' `import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;` segue o exemplo do seu código com select:

```
WebDriver driver = getHeadlessChrome();

try{
    driver.get("https://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/guiasinternet/Gare/Paginas/Gare.aspx");

    Select typeDropdown = new Select(webDriver.findElement(By.id("ReceitaTipo")));
    typeDropdown.selectByVisibleText("GNRE");

    Select codeDropdown = new Select(webDriver.findElement(By.id("CodigoReceita")));
    codeDropdown.selectByVisibleText("10002.1 - Energia Elétrica");

    driver.findElement(By.id("CnpjCpf")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("CnpjCpf")).sendKeys("087.271.516-54");
    driver.quit();

} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Outro detalhe, sua pergunta é muito interessante pra comunidade, já que ao que parece, no momento não tem uma resposta que resolva esse problema com os requerimentos que você precisa que são:

- Não abrir o navegador
- Não precisar de um .exe
- Ter suporte devido a execução de javascript.